# Prevent Man in The Middle Attack

Tags: javascript, man-in-the-middle

So I have a **React Native** App where a user can register. **React Native** uses the normal **JavaScript Fetch API**:

```js
fetch("http://myip:8000/api/account/register/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Accept": 'application/json',
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      username: username,
      password: password,
      email: email
    })
  })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    afterRegister(data)
  }
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

The problem is, that I also could make a **POST request** from e.g. **POSTMAN** :/ I thought about a security code, that I need to add to the body (hardcoded) that only the Client, who has the code could make a **POST request**. A code like this could look like this: **Dhiuw1298md()AJM8d9j289j)N ASIDH)8zh2n1ujD)(AZwh98em9812z)(ZDM)("ZM)8mdwuJio2h1hn398** and so on...

But now if I do this and a user register in the App he/she also could use a **man in the middle attack** to fetch the code and the spam **POST requests** to the Server until the Server crashes.

How can I prevent, that the user can see the content of the HTTP**S** POST Request with a **man in the middle attack**?

Comment: You are not using `https` in your example. Do you use `https` in your application? If so, how do you verify/check the server certificate?

Comment: A user doesn't need to man-in-the-middle themselves to see the content of a https request - transport encryption defends against *other* people reading what the user is sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also could make a POST request from e.g. POSTMAN :/
>
> […] spam POST requests to the Server until the Server crashes.

A code is only useful for authentication, i.e. identifying *which* user is sending the request to your server (and it's no good if the code is shared across all users, i.e. basically public). It doesn't help against a [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) - that's what a firewall is good for.